# submanifold and diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

Let $a$ be a positive integer and $M=$ {$(w,x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R} | aw^2+x^2+ay^2+z^2=1$}.
$$\\$$
a) Using the implicit function theorem or otherwise, show that $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4$.
$$\\$$(b) Consider $p=(0,1,0,0)\in M$.Compute $T_p M$ as a subspace of $T_p \mathbb{R}^4=\mathbb{R}^4$.
$$\\$$(c) What is the dimension of $M$?
$$\\$$ (d) Consider the function $\phi:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3: (w,x,y,z)\rightarrow (w+x,y,z).$ Show that $\phi$ is a loacal diffeomorphism at $p=(0,1,0,0)$.
$$\\$$
Please bear with me if I have asked so many naive questions, I am a undergrad student who did a little bit self study about differential geometry. I have no clue about this question and I guess question (a) is just to calculate the jacobian and is to show it is invertible? (b) I guess is just(0,2,0,0)? I guess (c) is to show it is a sphere inside $\mathbb{R}^4$ and hence $S^3$?.

Comment: The answer of the first question is litteraly in the question: use (correctly) the implicit function theorem. Then, the tangent subspace at $p$ will be the kernel of the tangent map at $p$ of a suitable function (see a). For c), just compute the dimension of the tangent space. For d), the answer is again in the question.

Comment: And could I ask how I could show (c) and (d)?

Comment: How would it be a subset consisting in $(w,y,z)$ if this kernel is a linear subspace of a four dimensional vector space?

Comment: Would $(2aw,2,2ay,2z)$ work?

Comment: I suggest you to take your time to understand every word in this problem and to look for right definitions before trying anything. What you stated is not even a linear subspace (it does not contain $0$).

Comment: Can I do partial derivative $(2aw,2x,2ay,2z)$ then shift by (0,1,0,0)? I literally don't know how to solve this question.